# Pass string in the type of NSObject

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, nsobject

I have one function where i use to pass object model. But in some case i need to pass only string. How can i do that ?

```
func push(destination: DestinationVC, object:NSObject?)
```

I have to pass one string value in object. What is did is :

```
self.delegate?.push(destination: NextVC, object: "message" as NSObject)
```

But i am passing string . Not an **NSObject**. What is the correct way of doing,

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: You could do `as NSString` since NSString is a subclass of NSObjecct but maybe the best solution is to not use NSObject at all in the function signature if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me try this one may be it will helps you

```
var str : NSString = "Hello, playground"
var strObject : NSObject = str as NSObject
print(str)
print(strObject)
```

output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJUVN.png)